# Is parametric form of a given function unique?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, parametric

1. Can we say that for any given function in single/multivariable, it is always possible to have a parametric form? (Elementary functions, complicated functions?)
2. Given any function, is parametric form uniquely determined?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: @AhaanS.Rungta I see you created the tag (concept) in [your edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1071928/revisions). I don't think that such tag is needed. But if you do think it could be useful, feel free to start a discussion about the new tag on meta. (This is irrelevant to the original question, so if some more discussion is needed, let us continue [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19159356#19159356).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No. Any parametric curve is a connected set (since it is the image of a connected set under a continuous mapping). But the set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 = 1\}$ consists of two disconnected lines, so it can't be represented using parametric equations (using continuous functions, anyway).
2. No. The parameterizations $t \mapsto(0,t)$ and $t \mapsto(0,1-t)$ both represent the same curve, for example. Even if you restrict $t$ to $[0,1]$, it's still true that both parameterizations give you the same curve segment.

See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375006/when-do-equations-represent-the-same-curve), which provides an example of two different parameterizations of a quadrant of a circle.

Answer (score 4):

1. In general, no. For example, many piecewise functions have no parametric forums. You will have to be more specific about this and if you clarify, I will edit this answer. For example, consider the [Dirichlet function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html). I don't know if you consider that in the set of functions you are asking about.
2. No. Quick counterexample. Take $ y = x $. The parametric equations $$ \begin {eqnarray*} x &=& t, \\ y &=& t \end {eqnarray*} $$and $$ \begin {eqnarray*} x &=& 2t, \\ y &=& 2t \end {eqnarray*} $$There are many other counterexamples.

Comment: For part 2. You get the same curve only if the domain is contained in $[0, \infty]$.

Comment: @bubba No? In both cases, $y=x$ for all $t$.

Comment: Yes, but the first parameterization gives you the entire line $y=x$, but the second one only gives you half of it.

Comment: Or, in fancy mathematician jargon: $\{(t,t) : t \in \mathbb{R}\} \ne \{(t^2,t^2) : t \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: Thanks; good point. Edited. Also, +1 on your answer.